# Phonegap/Cordova plugin in android studio

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

How to use Phonegap/Cordova plugin in android studio and how to create new project with phonegap modules?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yaa I got it. I installed PhoneGap plugin in Android Studio. By installing this, I can import all modules related PhoneGap.

[image]